# Why array is not updated in this example, strange?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Output should be [2,3,5,9] for both `a` and `b` as per me, as they both point to same address, and the data has a push of `9`. Why the result is still the old data of [2,3,5]?

```js
var a = [2,3,5];
var b = a; 
b.push[9];
console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: `It should be b.push(9);`

Comment: If you actually called the `push` method with parentheses, it’d work as expected.

Comment: If your next question is _“Why do `a` and `b` have the same content after only pushing to `b`?”_, please see [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](/q/29050004/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong brackets you need to do `b.push(9)`